# Is there a way to search a Pandas dataframe for date in Timestamp format?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have two datasets imported from Excel, both these datasets had a date column that pandas automatically converted into timestamp format. I need to trim one of the datasets based on the dates and time contained in the other dataset. But so far the only option that I have figured out is  iterating with two for loops over the two dataframes, that is both extremely inefficient and time consuming.

So I wanted to know if there is anyway in which I can search for and isolate individual rows of a dataframe based on timestamp data from another dataframe.

Here is a preview of the two datasets:

```
Date    Time    T
0   2017-09-12  23:00:00    31.0
1   2017-09-12  20:00:00    32.0
2   2017-09-12  17:00:00    34.5
3   2017-09-12  02:00:00    28.0
4   2017-09-11  23:00:00    29.5
... ... ... ...
13168   2005-02-03  17:00:00    19.0
13169   2005-02-02  23:00:00    13.0
13170   2005-02-02  17:00:00    18.0
13171   2005-02-01  23:00:00    11.8
13172   2005-02-01  17:00:00    18.5




  Date  Time    Gen
0   2005-06-01  21:00:00    1.024786
1   2005-06-02  21:00:00    1.040522
2   2005-06-03  21:00:00    1.031710
3   2005-06-04  21:15:15    1.056977
4   2005-06-05  21:00:00    1.000239
... ... ... ...
1128    2017-06-26  21:15:15    0.952850
1129    2017-06-27  20:30:30    0.863305
1130    2017-06-28  21:15:15    0.810412
1131    2017-06-29  20:30:30    0.828282
1132    2017-06-30  20:45:45    0.895405
```

For example, if I have two datasets

```
     Date    Time    T
1   2005-06-01  17:00:00    19.0
3   2005-06-02  23:00:00    13.0
3   2005-06-02  17:00:00    18.0
4   2005-06-03  23:00:00    11.8
5   2005-06-03  17:00:00    18.5
```

and

```
Date  Time    Gen
0   2005-06-01  21:00:00    1.024786
1   2005-06-02  23:00:00    1.040522
2   2005-06-03  23:00:00    1.031710
3   2005-06-04  23:15:15    1.056977
4   2005-06-05  23:00:00    1.000239
```

So based on the time and date data in the second dataset, I want to copy the T data from the first dataset. For instance, I have 2005-06-02, 23:00 in my second dataset, I want to copy the values having this exact date and time in the first dataset.

Comment: Looks like an inner merge on `Date, Time`. If not, can you provide two short dataframes and the expected output **from** them to show how you want to filter?

Comment: I added an example with two dataframes. Hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is it not `df1.merge(df2, on=['Date','Time'], how='left')`?